# Python Script "machine/user-level scripts" difference

Tags: python, notepad++

The [documentation](http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/usage.html) says

> The script called startup.py (in either the “machine” directory or
>   “user” directory - see Installation)

but all I can see in the "Installation" section is

> (machine-level scripts)

and

> (user level scripts go here).

What are those and where I should put my script files?

Answer (score 1):

As for me, the default Python Script installation did not work at all.

I suggest installing [Python Script 1.0.8.0](https://sourceforge.net/projects/npppythonscript/files/Python%20Script%201.0.8.0/).

Then, once you go to the *Plugins* -> *Python Script* -> *New Script*, you will be able to save and open scripts from the location that opens, or anywhere else where you have access.

Comment: You mean manual installation? Actually, installation from plugin manager don't work for me... I have currently working script inside **Notepad++\plugins\Config\PythonScript\scripts** but just realize that sample scripts come in **Notepad++\plugins\PythonScript\scripts**. Why there are two folders for scripts it remain a mystery...

Comment: Yes, download and install manually. I tried a lot of things, maybe not all, and decided to choose the easier way.

Comment: Now i see that **\Config\PythonScript** is not even included in archive I've installed (probably junk from broken manager installation) but I had 0.9.2.0 version which didn't give me any path with Python Scrip>New Script so I navigated there manually. I guess the other one should be used though the plugin recognizes both paths for me. This is pretty messy..